# Cannot renable wifi on Linux Mint 20.2 (Xfce)

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, networkmanager

I'm running linux mint 20.2 (Xfce). I'm also dual booting along side windows if that's relevant. When I booted into my computer this morning the WIFI was disabled. The <kbd>F12</kbd> button on my keyboard for enabling/disabling wireless is red, when it's usually blue.

I've tried enabling it again by pressing the button (with and without the function key) but that didn't work. I've also tired running `sudo service network-manager restart` which didn't help either. I've tried running `sudo rfkill list all` and `sudo rfkill unblock all` but none of the `rfkill` commands are out putting anything.

When I plug in my live USB (which I am using to post start this thread on the same hardware), the WiFi works perfectly fine.

Upon running `iwconfig` I get this output if this helps:

```
linkio@linkio:~$ iwconfig
anbox0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Output of `networkctl -a`:

```
linkio@linkio:~$ networkctl -a
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK   TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP    
  1 lo     loopback n/a         unmanaged
  2 enp8s0 ether    n/a         unmanaged
  3 anbox0 bridge   n/a         unmanaged

3 links listed.
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
linkio@linkio:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 062a:4101 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
linkio@linkio:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Let me know if you need anymore information, or have any solutions. Thanks.

-Linkio

Comment: I don't see a Wi-Fi adapter there at all, only wired, loopback and Anbox interface. Can you please post output of `networkctl -a`, `lsusb` and `lspci`?

Comment: I edited the initial post with those outputs. @Peregrino69

Comment: `systemd-networkd is not running` could be an issue, but my system shows the same, shows my Wi-Fi adapter and my Wi-Fi is working just fine so it's not where I'd look first. Also `lspci` shows Realtek RTL8188EE Wi-Fi adapter. That's a 2.4Gb/g/n chip - how old is this laptop? Do you have or can you get an external USB Wi-Fi adapter to test with? The on-board controller might be failing.

Comment: I don't think it's a hardware failure. When I plugged in a live USB running a different OS, the Wi-Fi works just fine. In-fact, it's how I started this thread on the same computer. It seems this is only happening on my Linux Mint partition. @Peregrino69

Comment: Those are sort of important details... please edit your question and add it there. Do the same for all new info so it's all immediately visible for anyone that might want to pitch in. If Live works, it def isn't HW - I'd look at driver failure next. I'd start by going through the system logs to see if there are any failures that might be related.

Comment: *I'm also dual booting along side windows if that's relevant.* It is relevant indeed. As always when dual-booting with Windows its Fast Startup feature MUST be disabled. This is just one of the problems it can cause if rebooting from Windows.